# How to do inter-process locking with forked Ruby processes?

Tags: ruby, locking, fork

#### Objective

Increment a counter using Ruby's `fork` method and several workers

#### Disclaimers

- I do **not** want to use any external dependencies for this
- Usage of Ruby's `Thread` class is **not** allowed
- I want to see if this is possible using `fork`

---

Here's a little shared memory mock

```
class Memory
  def self.address= value
    @value = value
  end

  def self.address
    @value
  end
end
```

Here's my worker

```
class Worker
  def initialize mutex
    @mutex = mutex
  end

  def work
    @mutex.synchronize do
      print "begin: %d " % (tmp=Memory.address)
      sleep 0.05
      print "end: %d \n" % (Memory.address = tmp + 1)
    end
  end
end
```

Let's run it

```
# init
Memory.address = 0
mutex = Mutex.new

# create workers
workers = []
10.times do
  workers << fork do
    Worker.new(mutex).work
  end
end

# wait for workers to finish
Process.waitall
```

#### Output

```
begin: 0 begin: 0 begin: 0 begin: 0 begin: 0 begin: 0 begin: 0 begin: 0 begin: 0 begin: 0 end: 1
end: 1
end: 1
end: 1
end: 1
end: 1
end: 1
end: 1
end: 1
end: 1
```

#### Expected Output

```
begin: 0 end: 1
begin: 1 end: 2
begin: 2 end: 3
begin: 3 end: 4
begin: 4 end: 5
begin: 5 end: 6
begin: 6 end: 7
begin: 7 end: 8
begin: 8 end: 9
begin: 9 end: 10
```

---

Side Questions:

- Am I supposed to be using a single Mutex?
- Does it matter if each worker creates its own Mutex?

Answer (score 2):

Forked processes inherit their parent's resources but the memory is a copy (or copy on write): the changes made in one process have no effect on the other ones.

Similarly each process has its own copy of the mutex, so the calls to synchronise don't achieve anything.

If you need to communicate with your child processes, one way is to use a pipe (see the docs for IO). Each process inherits a copy of the pipe and writes from one process show up in the other process.

```
child_in, parent_out = IO.pipe
parent_in, child_out = IO.pipe

Process.fork do
  parent_out.close
  parent_in.close
  #data written to child_out appears on parent_in in the parent process
  #reading from child_in returns data the parent has written to parent_out
end
child_out.close
child_in.close

#write data to parent_out here to have it appear on child_in in the child
#reading from parent_in to get data the child has written to child_out
```

As far as I know there are no cross process concurrency primitives built into ruby.

Comment: Probably you are correct, but when I insert `p @mutex` right below `def work`, it shows the same `object_id` for `@mutex` in all proccesses. How come?

Comment: That's normal. The process is copied, object ids and all

Comment: I am a noob to concurrent programming, so most of this stuff is already over my head. Is it possible you could show me a primitive pipe example?

Comment: I've added a snippet. It just a communication mechanism though - it doesn't handle synchronisation

Answer (score 1):

The File class has `flock` which lets you lock a file. It's one method to do inter-process locking.

There is even a gem called [`remote_lock`](http://dev.housetrip.com/2014/01/28/efficient-cross-processing-locking-in-ruby/) if you want to store it remotely.